# How to present the relationship between the following two variables in mathematical equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose, I have two clocks (C1 and C2) drifting from absolute time t, such that, C1(t) = Q1 t and C2(t) = Q2 t
Where, Q1 and Q2 are the drift coefficient.

How can I co relate them using equation?

Note that, in practice, the clocks time outweigh each other in every second, means, C1 may be lead 100 nanoseconds by C2 in one second but in the next second C2 leads by 200 nanoseconds and it happens randomly.

**Edit:1**

Clock drift in every second is a regular event but the drift is not linear. This sort of drift is very well known as clock skew. Suppose, the node clock deviated 100ns from the master clock (t) in the first second. Then, the node clock is updated accordingly. In the following second, the node clock shows a skew of 200 ns and then again get synchronized with the master clock. I want to get a relationship of such two node clocks where there has a common master clock. And both of them getting updated with the master clock in every second again deviated within this period randomly.

[(Link) This is the resultant offsets between two such nodes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjmJf.png)

**Edit:2**

Node clocks are 1pps disciplined clock. Means their value changes in every second. So the drift is due to the clock skew.

Therefore, the general clock equation is: 
*Ci(t)= t + Q(t)*

Where t is the gps time (i.e.reference time or master clock time).
*t= t_gps= t_utc+ δ_io*

Here,
δ_io= time difference between UTC time and GPS time is a constant value.

Hence,
*Ci(t)=t_utc+ δ_io+ Q (t)*

Where Q(t) is the node clock offsets relative to the GPS clock. η(t) is the skew between GPS clock and node clock whereas λ(t) is drift. 
Q (t)= η (t)+ λ (t)

As node clock is subjected to guided by 1pps signal for every second the node suffers only skew η(t_gps ).

Thus,

For node n1, the clock equation is
**C1(t) = t + Q1(t)**
For node n2,
**C2(t)  = t + Q2(t)**

And the relation between C1(t) and C_2(t) is,
**C1(t)= Q12.C2(t)**

Where Q12 is relative skew between the receivers.

**Edit:3** 
There is a general model of clock synchronization between Master and Slave node as in the following reference:
[Snap-Ref-1 and Ref-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWp4r.png)

All I want to get a relationship between two nodes that are synchronized with a common master clock (GPS clock). While GPS is master, there is no drift but skew, means λ is zero. Thus, 
Q (t)= η (t) 
Now recalling,
For node n1, the clock equation is
**C1(t) = t + Q1(t)**
For node n2,
**C2(t)  = t + Q2(t)**

And the relation between C1(t) and C_2(t) is,
**C1(t)= Q12.C2(t)**

So, Q1(t) and Q2(t) is time varying. But according to the **Reference 2** from the snap above Q12 is not directly time t varying but C2(t) varying. I just need to ensure the philosophy behind this. Whether this expression is okay?

Comment: The first sentence seems to say that each clock drifts away from correct time in a highly regular manner. But then the last sentence seems to say the clocks behave in an entirely unpredictable way. Please edit your question so it makes sense.

Comment: Clock drift in every second is a regular event but the drift is not linear. This sort of drift is very well known as clock skew. Suppose, the node clock deviated 100ns from the master clock (t) in the first second. Then, the node clock is updated accordingly. In the following second, the node clock shows a skew of 200 ns and then again get synchronized with the master clock. I want to get a relationship of such two node clocks where there has a common master clock. And both of them getting updated with the master clock in every second again deviated within this period randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean every drift is a random variable, unknown, $dt_i$, with some distribution?, and at some regular time instants $t_i=iT$, the clocks get synchronized to the universal time? So you are meaning some sort of a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk_hypothesis), [wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process), between every synchronization?

Question to the OP (you):
So, how these drifts are ocurring, ***precisely***? Totally random, deterministic but unknown? known through a nonlinear function? through a dynamical nonlinear system?

Edit:
I am afraid a simple model cannot be expressed in a simple way from the plot you have shown. There is a tendency, but the data is really few for infer anything else. At this moment, the time offset in $ns$ is gaussian, and with standard deviation around $7ns$, with a mean which is oscillating in turn to zero. 
$$
\theta\sim N(\mu(t),\sigma(t))\\
\sigma(t)\approx 0.7\\
\mathbb{E}\mu(t)=-3.6
$$

Again, this is very vague and rough, and a probabilistic approach. Just an idea on what you should look if you do not have anything else.

Edit.

From the reference, the main problem is still, to find the distribution for the skew variable $\theta$ (the deviation between the master clock and the slave).

Assuming the data already includes adjustment events between master and slave, it is then required to know where those events happens, and after that, we could estimate the skew distribution. This is, the time history you show must be divided in $n$ pieces, delimited by $n$ synchonization events, and then take those pieces as different realizations of the skew process, trending from zero (when the clocks are perfectly synchronized) to $\theta_i$ (the deviation immediately before a synchronization).

Again, without that information, very few can be estimated.

As given above, a simple guess can be assuming the $\omega$ distribution is a linear combination between a random walk variable and a random variable:
$$
\omega_i=\alpha{\omega_w}_i+\beta{\omega_n}_i\\
{\omega_w}_i-{\omega_w}_{i-1} \sim N(0,1)\\
 \omega_n \sim N(0,1)\\
$$

Before proceeding further... check this very simple noise model, using $\alpha=0.5$ and $\beta=2$. Can you say, this looks familiar?

```
% Delay Model
rng(5);
t=(0:1/60:5.5)';
n=length(t);
e=randn(n,1)
o1=e*10;
o2=cumsum(e)/sqrt(n)*15;
o=0.5*o1+2*o2
stem(t,o);
```

[image]

Comment: Some terms are not clear to me thus can't answer directly. However, I have added a graph in original post of the relative offsets(drift) between such nodes that are synchronized with a master clock and updates in every second. tanx

Comment: Thanks. You sound good in math. However, I have tried to establish the relationship in other ways (above edit:2) ( the relationship between two node clocks that follows same master clock). Do you think this relationship reflects the graphical results as well?
Afterall, in y-axes, the value is the time offsets between the two clocks which have been represented wrt reference time (x-axes value).

Comment: There were some notations misleading. Now corrected.

Comment: Do you have some plot for $\eta$ and $\lambda$?. Still, with only one variable plotted, i suppose it is $Q(t)$, it is almost impossible to know more, and also, to model more. Or $\eta$ is a mean trend constant and $\lambda$ is a zero centered random vabiable?. Again, if you have more data, a more proper model can be formulated. In the plot, -3.6 is $\eta$, $\lambda$, none of them?

Comment: I actually don't have any plots individually of η and λ. I do have only the final offsets between two slave nodes.
However, I have made another edit to get an impression about the relationship (correlation) between two slaves. I don't get confident enough having this expression but need to express somehow to get a meaningful expression for the result. I can't add more picture as I am not yet permitted to :(

Comment: I dont understand the edit....

Comment: Thanks for your updates. I will get back here with a clear outline soon.